# multiple input arrays codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

i have a problem in codeigniter project .
codeignter has filter and delete keys of array and also some value .
my html is

```html
<input type="text" name="n['rrr'][]">
<input type="text" name="n['rrr2'][]">
```

and php code

```
echo "<pre>";
        print_r($_POST['n']);
        echo "</pre>";
```

and also i add same code to begin of index.php in the root path

result is

```html
Array
(
    ['rrr'] => Array
        (
            [0] => llll
        )

    ['rrr2'] => Array
        (
            [0] => kkkkkk
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => kkkkkk
        )

)
```

array 1 is showed from index
and second from the controller .

and thanks .

Comment: Spit more better organized code in here. It is very unclear what do you have there or what is your intention. I have no clue what does "and second from the controller" mean. Check [here](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) how to write good question.

Comment: what you want to achieve and what actual problem u facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<input type="text" name="n[rrr][]">
<input type="text" name="n[rrr2][]">
```